# How can I look for software on my machine which could be installed from Homebrew, but currently isn't?

Tags: homebrew, package-management, 3rd-party

So assume there are various apps on my machine which I installed manually at some point WITHOUT using brew. Reasons for that could include:

1. I specifically decided *not* to use brew, even though I could have.
2. This software wasn't included in brew yet at that time.
3. It was before I even *started* using brew altogether.

Now, let's say I'd like to look for software on my computer, which now *does* exist on Homebrew, but I don't have that version installed. Is there some streamlined, automatic way to find and list these? Or would I need to go through all my apps and check, one-by-one?

Comment: You could do something like `cd /usr/local/bin; for b in *; do brew search $b; done` but the output might be hard to process (and it doesn't include casks).

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes you'd have to check one by one. Any approach like above could work but is not guaranteed to find everything